# Using sub query in in group by sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello everyone I would like to use sub query as code bellow but it get error I would like to to ask you that I how can i do this. Thanks!

```
SELECT HR_EMPMAST.DEPT,HR_DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DEPARTMENT,HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE,HR_JOBFUNCTION.DESCRIPTION AS POSITION,
COUNT(HR_EMPMAST.EMPCODE) ACTUAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.EMPTYPE='LOCAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LOCALEMP,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.EMPTYPE='EXPAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPATEMP--,
(SELECT EMPNO FROM HR_HEADCOUNT WHERE POSITION=HR_EMPMAST.JOBCODE AND INMONTH=1 AND INYEAR=2017) AS EMPNO
FROM HR_EMPMAST 
LEFT JOIN HR_DEPARTMENT 
ON HR_EMPMAST.DEPT = HR_DEPARTMENT.CODE 
LEFT JOIN HR_JOBFUNCTION 
ON HR_EMPMAST.JOBCODE=HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE 
WHERE HR_EMPMAST.CAREERDESC <> 'TERMIMATE'  
GROUP BY HR_EMPMAST.DEPT,HR_DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION,HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE,HR_JOBFUNCTION.DESCRIPTION
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Show us the error message - as text. 2) Try to format your code.

Comment: Could you click on 'enter image description here'

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please, use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

Second: you need to add ALL columns from SELECT to GROUP BY (but not ones in SUM and COUNT functions).

Third: you got strange `EMPNO` select. Maybe better way is to use `JOIN`?

Try to use this one:

```
SELECT  e.DEPT,
        d.DESCRIPTION AS DEPARTMENT,
        jf.CODE,
        jf.DESCRIPTION AS POSITION,
        COUNT(e.EMPCODE) ACTUAL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.EMPTYPE='LOCAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LOCALEMP,
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.EMPTYPE='EXPAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPATEMP,
        hc.EMPNO
FROM HR_EMPMAST e
LEFT JOIN HR_DEPARTMENT d
    ON e.DEPT = d.CODE 
LEFT JOIN HR_JOBFUNCTION jf
    ON e.JOBCODE = jf.CODE
LEFT JOIN HR_HEADCOUNT hc
    ON hc.POSITION = e.JOBCODE AND hc.INMONTH=1 AND hc.INYEAR=2017
WHERE e.CAREERDESC <> 'TERMIMATE'  
GROUP BY e.DEPT,
        d.DESCRIPTION,
        jf.CODE,
        jf.DESCRIPTION,
        hc.EMPNO
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you for you answer it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query or include `HR_EMPMAST.JOBCODE` in group by clause...

```
SELECT HR_EMPMAST.DEPT,HR_DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION AS DEPARTMENT,HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE,HR_JOBFUNCTION.DESCRIPTION AS POSITION,
COUNT(HR_EMPMAST.EMPCODE) ACTUAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.EMPTYPE='LOCAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LOCALEMP,
SUM(CASE WHEN HR_EMPMAST.EMPTYPE='EXPAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPATEMP,

em.EMPNO AS EMPNO

FROM HR_EMPMAST

LEFT JOIN (SELECT POSITION, EMPNO FROM HR_HEADCOUNT WHERE INMONTH=1 AND INYEAR=2017) em on em.POSITION=HR_EMPMAST.JOBCODE

LEFT JOIN HR_DEPARTMENT 
ON HR_EMPMAST.DEPT = HR_DEPARTMENT.CODE 
LEFT JOIN HR_JOBFUNCTION 
ON HR_EMPMAST.JOBCODE=HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE 
WHERE HR_EMPMAST.CAREERDESC <> 'TERMIMATE'  
GROUP BY HR_EMPMAST.DEPT,HR_DEPARTMENT.DESCRIPTION,HR_JOBFUNCTION.CODE,HR_JOBFUNCTION.DESCRIPTION
```